# How do I save my order entry price to a variable

Tags: pine-script

Not sure how to retrieve my order entry price.
I'm new to pine scipt
I will use the order entry to plot some target hlines

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
myOrderEntryPrice = strategy.position_avg_price
```

Works for single position trades. The `strategy.position_avg_price` changes when you have multiple positions open.